# Change JSON value for a key which can be nested in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I don't know if there is a quicker way or a function that's already implemented for my issue. I have a nested dynamic JSON with *unique* keys.

```
{
    "Key1": true,
    "Key2": false,
    "Key3": "just a string",
    "Key4": {
               "Key5": "just a string",
               "Key6": 51,
               "Key7": {
                           "Key8": "this value has to be changed"
                       }
            }
}
```

Is there any Swift function or a package that could do this easily like that:

```
let updatedJSON = originalJSON.update(key: "Key8", with: "---")
```

So the updatedJSON will be the same only "Key8" will be updated. Take into consideration that I don't know the hierarchy. The JSON key positions may wary. Sometimes Key8 can be at the root of the object.

Comment: SwiftyJSON https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON is the best fit for this.

Comment: I looked over it. Can you provide an example of how to use it?

Comment: let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
  //Now you got your value
}

Comment: No, it's not ok. I don't know what's the hierarchy. I only know that somewhere in this JSON there's a key called "Key8". For your example, I have to know the hierarchy.

Comment: Then write that in your question, it's not clear that the json message may vary

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to read the json message into a string and then use a regular expression to find and replace the value for `key8`, that is if the message isn't to large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing the structure of your JSON complicates this problem a bit, but it can still be solved. I've come up with an idea to recursively search through a Dictionary

```
extension Dictionary
{
    mutating func updateValueRecursively(forKey key : Key, newValue: Value) -> Bool
    {
        if keys.contains(key)
        {
            self[key] = newValue
            return true
        }
        for (_, value) in enumerated()
        {
            if var dict = value.value as? Dictionary<Key, Value> {
                if dict.updateValueRecursively(forKey: value.key, newValue: newValue), let newDict = dict as? Value {
                    self[value.key] = newDict
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Of course you will first have to turn your JSON string to a Dictionary

```
var dict : Dictionary<String : Any>
if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
do {
    dict=  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```